# Fedora 34 won't start after removing graphics card (headless)

Tags: fedora, headless

After installing Fedora 34 Workstation (vanilla configuration with default partitions), it starts fine with the graphics card installed but no monitor attached. However, if I remove the graphics card, it will not boot (or at least, I can't connect over ssh). I can boot with the graphics card and then pull it, but that's not really ideal. The problem is that the graphics card fan is noisy, and I only need it for the install. The CPU is an i7-77ooK, so of course it has on-board graphics. Why is this a problem?

Comment: You will have to connect a monitor to it, using the iGPU, and provide us with something that indicates the problem.

Comment: I'm connected now, but I don't know how to identify the problem because of course the current session has started normally (with the graphics card attached, and no monitor plugged into it). Suggestions?

Comment: If you leave the driver in place when you remove the hardware; so there is no hardware for the driver - might that be the actual problem?

Comment: @Hannu That could be, I really have no idea. Is there an easy way to remove the driver via bash? I'm connected on ssh with root.

Comment: Are you using the default drivers or did you enable / install the Nvidia binary driver?

Comment: @mattdm It's a fresh vanilla install from the official Fedora 34 ISO, no additional drivers installed.

Comment: Weird. I'd check your BIOS settings for, well, first whether the integrated GPU is enabled, and second for any sort of halt-on-error options.

Comment: The integrated graphics appears to be enabled because I can hot-unplug the graphics card after the system boots and everything continues to work like normal, including a VirtualBox running Windows (accessed over RDP) and firefox over SSH. Nothing in the system depends on the card, but some part of the startup configuration requires it anyway. This would seem to be a bug in the Fedora boot sequence, where correct behavior would be to ignore the absence of the original video output and just use whatever is available.